# Green oks when I boot up ubuntu

Tags: boot

I just reinstalled ubuntu, and it works fine otherwise, but when I boot up the computer, under the "349140350/4314319853319 blocks" message (The numbers are made up but you get the point) there's a bunch of words that weren't there in my first installation, that list stuff like drivers and they have green 'ok's next to them. Is this normal behavior?

If I knew how to grab that text to paste here I would, but I also have no idea how to access that.

Answer (score 1):

You can review this output with `cat /var/log/boot.log` in a terminal window (Ctrl-Alt-T) - or `/var/log/kern.log`, depending on your version.

Green OKs are of course OK. Bad signs would be red 'Failed'. If you don't want to see these boot activities, you can add 'quiet' to the boot options.

Comment: I don't see a boot.log in that folder. Is there any other possible candidate name?

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer.

Comment: I looked at the kern.log file, but it doesn't look like the text that I saw.

Comment: With `find /var/log -mtime -1` you see all log files that have been written in one day. If you noticed some particular name or word in your "bunch of words" you can search for it in these files with `grep <word> <filename>`.